# Appending values in a string in java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I have a REST API test suite where certain URIs are used repeatedly. Thus, I created a separate class with `public static final` members. Something like:

```
  public class RestURI {
        public RestURI(){}
        public static final String getAllShipsURI = "/ship/manager/ships";
        public static final String getAllPortsURI = "/port/manager/ports";
    }
```

However, is there a way to deal with URIs like this:

```
/infrastructure/ships/docked/" + shipId + "/capacity
```

I am looking for a way such that I can declare the URL like above in the RestURI class and still specify values in the test when I use them.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html  might give you some insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a constant *format*, rather than a String and use a static getter:

```
public static String getShipUri(int shipId) {
    return String.format("/infrastructure/ships/docked/%d/capacity", shipId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use String.format. Like this:

```
public class RestURI {
    public RestURI(){}
    public xxx() {
       int shipId = 219001000;
       ... String.format(dockedShipURIFormat, shipId) ...;
    }
    public static final String dockedShipURIFormat = "/infrastructure/ships/docked/%d/capacity";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [ANTLR StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) for exactly this on multiple occasions.  The ability to have inline macro parsing and a little if..else logic in the templates is pretty powerful, and it maintains good readability.